# Access field with @Transient in JPA query

Tags: jpql

I have an entity with a transient attribute:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset")
public class Asset {
    @Transient
    private String locationIdentifier = "N/A";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostLoad
    private void onPostLoad() {
        if (location != null) {
            locationIdentifier = location.getIdentifier();
        }
    }

   [other stuffs]

   }
```

I tried to access `locationIdentifier` this way in JPA:

```
String sqlString = "SELECT asset FROM Asset WHERE asset.locationIdentifier = :inputstr";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlString);
```

But I got an error: `Cannot resolve the property locationIdentifier`

I want to ask how I access `locationIdentifier` using JPQL?

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

JPQL queries are transformed to SQL queries and SQL queried operate to the data in database. Marking property transient means that property is not persisted to the database and consequently it cannot be queried from the database.

Answer (score 1):

@Transient means that the attribute is totally ignored by JPA.  It cannot be referred to in a query.

Simply remove `@Transient` and it should work.

Also, you need to provide the parameter value to the query:

```
String sqlString = "SELECT asset FROM Asset WHERE asset.locationIdentifier = :inputstr";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlString);
query.setParameter("inputstr", someValue);
```

Comment: I know that, but if we remove `@Transient`, JPA will create a column for it in the table and that what I don't need. Btw, thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's bad luck. You must have the column in the DB to use it in the JPA query.  Think about it - the JPA query is converted to SQL and entirely executed in the DB.  The query is not executed in java memory.  The SQL result set is convert to java objects/attributes using JPA ORM mappings.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either you add column locationIdentifier in your db table and unmark it as Transient, or you cannot use this column in queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a transient Member in a query. Thats makes no sense! JPQL is used to get something from the database, and if there is no "locationIdentifier" you can't add this to your where-clause. What would you expect in SQL if there is no such database-field?