# alternative of @formula in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there any alternative sollution for @formula which is using in hibernate? I need to use it by jpa, for instance:

```
@Formula("select count(1) from Market m where m.defaultAirportCode=airportCode")
private Boolean isDefault;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use combination of annotations and one method

```
@Transient
private Boolean isDefault;

@PostLoad
private void setDefault() {
this.isDefault=this.defaultAirportCode.equals(this.airportCode);
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you can't use transient fields in JPQL. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154535/access-field-with-transient-in-jpa-query

Comment: this is not downside, this is how `@Transient` is working, but I'll ask you a question {is `@Formula` work with JPQL ?}

Comment: @BassemRedaZohdy - I think no, I can not access it, unfortunately - I try to access it in native JPQL query and it says that it does not exist :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use a database view that includes the formula, and map the Entity to the view.

Comment: Is it possible to access the view in a native query using JPQL?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no pure JPA alternative for @formula annotation.