# JPA alternative for hibernate formula

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Hibernate `@Formula` annotation is used to perform calculations on database instead of JVM (aggregate functions for example) and map a result to entity field. This is useful in cases where a property of an entity must be derived from arbitrary tables. Downside is the intrusion of SQL in the application layer.

Is there an JPA standard for the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any annotation like Hibernate's @Formula in JPA. Here's more: [alternative of @formula in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318500/alternative-of-formula-in-jpa)